# Django Rest Setup for Foreign key values

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have an alert system for the users. users can subscribe to the categories and based on that i will generate alert.

I have defined the Models for alert like this.

```
class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class Area(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    city = models.ForeignKey(City)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class SubscribeAlert(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    status = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    attributes = JSONField('Subscriptions', null=True, blank=True)


class SubscribeLocation(models.Model):
    subscribe = models.ForeignKey(SubscribeAlert)
    area = models.ForeignKey(Area)
```

Users can choose the category and select multiple area for the notification.
Is this my model structure is ok for this scenario ?

And How can I define rest ModelSerializer insert  SubscribeAlert and many SubscribeLocation at the same time.?

```
class NotifyCreateSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = SubscribeAlert
```

How can I extend this to create the subscription ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [nested serializers](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships). Here is example(might not work)

```
class SubscribeLocationSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = SubscribeLocation

class NotifyCreateSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    subscribelocation_set = SubscribeLocationSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = SubscribeAlert
        fields = ('category', 'user', 'status', 'attributes',
                  'subscribelocation_set')
```

Comment: "Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got int.". I pass area ids as like this .

Comment: {
            "category": 1,
            "user": 1,
            "status": false,
            "attributes": null,
            "subscribelocation_set": [1,2,3]
        } How to map the SubscribeAlert with this?

Comment: `subscribelocation_set` should contain dicts. "subscribelocation_set": [{data1}, {data2}]

Comment: @KareshA If you want to do this with ids. You need to orerride `create` and `update` serialezer methods http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#saving-instances

Comment: Yes My db model design is not correct. I have to create ManyToManyField to Area SubscribeAlert inside I will try that.